# .objects.all() query not working in Django

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I am developing a website which is based on information about books and i want to display all the authors present in the 'Authors' table in an HTML page. When i click on the link "authors", the page is not rendered and it gives an error "User matching query does not exist." (Not letting me post the image here).
This is the traceback from the terminal.

```
Internal Server Error: /books/authors/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pallav\PycharmProjects\onlineBookStore\onlineBookStore\books\views.py", line 35, in follow_user
    user_to_be_followed = User.objects.get(username=username)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

I tried running the query in `python manage.py shell` and it yields a proper query set.

My `urls.py` file is:

```
app_name = 'books'

urlpatterns = [
    # /books/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # /register/
    url(r'register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

    # /logout/
    url(r'logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),

    # /login/
    url(r'login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),

    # /search/
    url(r'search/$', views.search, name='search'),

    # /add_book/
    url(r'search/(?P<isbn>[0-9]+)/add_book$', views.add_book, name='add_book'),

    # /books/<book_id>/
    url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # /books/favorite/
    url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),

    # /books/rate/
    url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/rate/$', views.rate, name='rate'),

    # /books/review/
    url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/review/$', views.review, name='review'),

    # /books/borrow/
    url(r'^(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/borrow/$', views.borrow, name='borrow'),

    # books/user_profile/
    url(r'user_profile/$', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),

    # books/edit_profile
    url(r'edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),

    # books/login_btn
    url(r'login_btn/$', views.login_btn, name='login_btn'),

    # books/show_users
    url(r'show_users/$', views.show_users, name='show_users'),

    # books/<username>/
    url(r'^(?P<username>[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*)/$', views.follow_user, name='follow_user'),

    # books/authors/
    url(r'authors/$', views.authors, name='authors'),
]
```

My View function is:

```
def authors(request):
    all_authors = Authors.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'books/authors.html', {'all_authors': all_authors})

def follow_user(request, username):
    user_following = request.user

    if user_following is not None:
        user_to_be_followed = User.objects.get(username=username)
        Follow.objects.add_follower(user_following, user_to_be_followed)
        return render(request, 'books/test.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'books/registration_form.html')
```

My Html page authors.html is:

```
{% extends 'books/base.html' %}

{% block title %}All authors{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    <div class="users-container container-fluid">

        <!-- Books -->
        <div class="row">
            {% if all_authors %}
                {% for author in all_authors %}

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <h1>{{ author.name }}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <h3>Currently no authors available</h3>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The view function "follow_user" is just for an entry into the database, it does not have an HTML page associated with it.

test.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% load friendshiptags %}


    <h1> {% following request.user %} </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I have visited different links to the similar questions but none of them solves my problem. link1: [objects.all() query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630835/objects-all-query-not-working)
link2: [Django objects.all() empty query set, not empty in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850585/django-objects-all-empty-query-set-not-empty-in-shell)

The help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at your stack trace once again. The view you have supplied is not the one causing the problem. The problem arises when calling `user_to_be_followed = User.objects.get(username=user_id)` in `  File "C:\Users\Pallav\PycharmProjects\onlineBookStore\onlineBookStore\books\views.py", line 35, in follow_user`

Comment: as seen you are not making any query in function. Surely your problem is in the urls.py. Post your full urls.py code

Comment: fine then, @alasdair's edited answer should work for you.

Comment: As an aside, you should use post requests instead of get requests when you follow/unfollow users, because you're changing data. Once you have made the changes, the usual practice is to redirect instead of rendering a view.

Comment: Noted! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

Your request to `/books/authors/` is being handled by the `follow_user` view, because they both match, and the `follow_user` pattern is above the `authors` pattern.

```
# books/<username>/
url(r'^(?P<username>[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*)/$', views.follow_user, name='follow_user'),

# books/authors/
url(r'authors/$', views.authors, name='authors'),
```

You could fix this by changing the regexes so that they don't clash, or by moving the `authors` pattern above the `follow_user` pattern (note this will stop you from following a user with `username='authors'`).

Once you've fixed your URL patterns, the traceback suggests that there is a problem in your `follow_user` view that you should fix:

```
user_to_be_followed = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

If there is a chance that the user does not exist in the database, then you'll want to handle this possibility as well. You could catch the exception:

```
try:
    user_to_be_followed = User.objects.get(username=username)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    user_to_be_followed = None
```

Or perhaps you could use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

user_to_be_followed = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

Finally, note that the following check is incorrect:

```
user_following = request.user 
if user_following is not None:
    ...
```

If the user is not logged in, then `request.user` will be an anonymous user, it won't be `None`. You should check `if request.user.is_authenticated:` in Django 1.10+, or `if request.user.is_authenticated():` in earlier versions.

Comment: The authors module does not require any user nor it is making a query to the user table. Also, the authors table is nowhere related to the user table (read: foreign_key etc). I don't know why traceback shows that statement. I will edit my question to include those details too. Also, i made a mistake in naming. user_id is actually the username. Thanks for that, i will fix it.

Comment: The traceback shows you where the error is occuring. If the code is not in your `authors` view, that means that Django is not running the authors view. You might have an error in your url patterns (e.g. a regex that is missing `$`) - you haven't shown your complete urls so I can't tell.

Comment: If you've changed the code you should add the new traceback -- you shouldn't have `User.objects.get(username=user_id)` in the traceback anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! It worked. And sorry for the incompetent framing of the question. I am new to this. Still learning :)

Comment: Glad it worked. As you get more practice, reading the tracebacks gets easier, and you'll be able to pinpoint the problem quicker :)

Answer (score 3):

The code you showed us seems fine, but somewhere in your code you have this line :

```
User.objects.get(username=user_id)
```

Since you try to match an id with a username, it won't find anything and when `get()` finds nothing it throws an exception.

You should do something to catch the errors, like `except User.DoesNotExists` and fix your condition of course.